# Laravel api foreach argument must be of type array|object, null given in

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, curl

i am getting product data from API end.
there are two nested "data" in the incoming array.
i can list the products with foreach, but I can't reach a single element.
when I try a few methods, it returns errors like "array,object int". Where am I going wrong and how can I access its elements?

the method i'm trying now is this and i'm applying this process on the Laravel side.

```
{
    "data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 101553,
                "company_id": 730,
                "category_id": 132288,
                "brand_id": 39549,
                "name": "Hh PRODUCT TEST",
                "remote_category_id": "scarf",
                "remote_brand_id": "bershka123",
                "spu": "zb3940823904"
            },
            {
                "id": 101554,
                "company_id": 730,
                "category_id": 132289,
                "brand_id": 39549,
                "name": "Hs PRODUCT TEST",
                "remote_category_id": "scarf",
                "remote_brand_id": "bershka123",
                "spu": "zb3940823905"
            }
        ],
        "count": 175,
        "search": {
            "category_id": null,
            "brand_id": null,
            "company_id": null
        },
        "start": 0,
        "length": 10
    },
    "error_code": 0,
    "message": ""
}
```

Model:

```
 public function getProducts($start =0, $length =10, $category_id =null, $brand_id=null, $spu=null, $name=null, $is_active=null, $id=null, $remote_brand_id = null, $remote_category_id=null)
    {
        $request = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->jwttoken,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ])->post($this->sandbox . 'products/search',[
            "start" => $start,
            "length" => $length,
            "search" => [
                "category_id" => $category_id,
                "brand_id" => $brand_id,
                "spu" => $spu,
                "name" => $name,
                "is_active" => $is_active,
                "id" => $id,
                "remote_brand_id" => $remote_brand_id,
                "remote_category_id" => $remote_category_id
            ]
        ])->json();
        return $request;
    }
```

controller

```
    $company_id = 100;
    $products = (new Client($company_id))->getProducts();
    foreach($products as $product){
        foreach($product as $prd){
            dump($prd);
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
0 => array:27 [
    "id" => 101530
    "company_id" => 730
    "category_id" => 132047
    "brand_id" => 39316
    "name" => "Hs Test Shoe"
    "remote_category_id" => "5a39b114f1ff6e42639e9e041cd002d6"
    "remote_brand_id" => "617392d2b51dbba1a2e5561a3e4eefe7"
    "spu" => "845504"
],
1 => array:36 [
    "id" => 231303
    "company_id" => 730
    "product_id" => 101530
    "supplier_id" => null
    "remote_supplier_id" => null
    "name" => "Hd Test Shoe"
    "description" => "This is a test product."
    "sku" => "2K4F9966WHITE42"
]
```

ErrorException :
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, int given

How do i get the correct loop format and elements?

Comment: your dump method is producing a result as you say. where is the error happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop like this way

```
foreach($products["data"]["data"] as $product)
{
    dump($product);
}
```

Comment: actually i tried it and didn't get any results but now it worked! I did not understand. Thank you.

Comment: It will happen sometime like that but don't worry I am here to help you.